# Join all tables at once or multiple queries?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am using Spring JDBC and I wonder what is the best: joining all tables so that I can get all the associations for the object I want to populate or do multiple select queries? How do you deal with joining of tables in Spring when you need to join more that one table to get all the data of the object?

Comment: Depends on how large your tables are, and what columns you're after.

Comment: It vary from 10 to 2000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is better to join as many tables as you will reference from your object. It is unlikely that the number of columns you bring back will be so excessive as to outweigh the disadvantage of making multiple calls to the database for the rest of your data.

The only real exception to this is if you want data from a many to one association. So, for example, if you are selecting a `Car` and join on the `Wheel`s, you will get back four rows for each car which is not really a problem. However, if you join on `Wheels` and `Seats`, you will get back 16 rows for a car with 4 seats. This kind of joining creates a cartesian product, so a second query to get seats would probably be warranted in this case unless you will only ever be selecting a few cars.

To address the problem of rewriting mapping code when you join using Spring JDBC, consider breaking out your RowMappers. Disclaimer: I mostly use Hibernate and am not as familiar with Spring's JdbcTemplate though I have used it some. Let me give an example for a one-to-one join:

```
private Car mapCar(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    Car car = null;
    while (rs.next()) {
        if (car == null) {
            Long carId = rs.getLong("ID");
            String model = rs.getString("MODEL");
            car= new Car(carId, model);
        }
        car.setEngine(mapEngine(rs));
    }
    return car;
}
```

You could either have a `mapEngine()` method in `CarRepository` that is specific to cars or you could make a public `mapEngine()` method on your `EngineRepository` class that you call from `mapCar()`. If you go with the latter, you may have name conflicts so aliasing your select variables may be in order. Even so, if `CarMapper` and `EngineMapper` both have `rs.getLong("ID")` in them, you may have no choice but to create a separate public mapper. So you might have a public method like:

```
public Engine mapEngineShared(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    Engine engine = new Engine();
    engine.setId("ENGINE_ID"); // Aliased from "ID"
    engine.setId("ENGINE_MODEL_TYPE"); // Aliased from "MODEL_TYPE"
    return engine;
}
```

And in whatever query that will map this way, make sure to alias your engine fields with `ENGINE_` for compatibility with the shared mapper. It's not an ideal solution, but would save you from having duplicate mapping code everywhere.

For one-to-many associations, you would need to use a `ResultSetExtractor` since `RowMappers` only handle a row at a time and would give you duplicate `Cars` for every `Wheel`. The approach would be the same though, reusing `RowMappers` where appropriate.

If you end up using complex joins a lot because your data model and business logic tend to necessitate them and you find the creation of mappers to be awkward, you might consider an ORM solution which would handle the mapping for you. Then again, if you don't really see any performance problems from not using joins, you may be better off using them rarely and sticking with the simplicity of JdbcTemplate.

Comment: I see, but what is best practice in Spring JDBC when you extract data from multiple tables and when you want to reuse the mapping logic?

Comment: I think that's something you'll have to feel out a bit. You certainly don't want to be rewriting RowMappers every time you join something new, but some additional mapping logic is unavoidable. I'll update my answer with an example.